# VM shutdown all the timeout - FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, android-studio

Trying to start my apps.
but as soon i add the phonenumber to login i get error.
I have search all day with no luck.

Hope someone can help me.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xxxxxxxx.user, PID: 1234
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.xxxxxxxx.user.Models.UserResponse.isError()' on a null object reference
at com.xxxxxxxx.user.Activities.otpscreen$4$1.onResponse(otpscreen.java:145)
at retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(DefaultCallAdapterFactory.java:83)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

otpscreen.java:145

```
if(!response.body().isError()){
UserResponse userResponse = response.body();
emilto = userResponse.getUser().getEmail();
phone_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
verify_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mProg.dismiss();
}else{
mProg.dismiss();
startActivity(new Intent(otpscreen.this, RegisterActivity.class));
Toast.makeText(otpscreen.this, "Please Register: "+ response.body().getMessage() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like your response doesn't contain isError boolean. Put the breakpoint to if statement and check your response with debugger.

Comment: im pretty new to android studio, how do you mean with ( Put your breakpoint to if statement )

Comment: Follow instructions: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#startdebug

Comment: i have tryed debug, still error, still confuse :(